# Audio Live stream from Android to my laptop

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I have a project where I want to implement live audio stream from users with Android phones in my LAN Network and receive them in my laptop, off which I can filter, reduce noise, control volumes of each and write the audio to the speakers.

Please help. If possible Android and Java.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: The issue is not the code.  With Java and Android, it was impossible to stream live audio. Though there are apps that don't hear streaming

Comment: You can find an example in my question how you can start implementation this player for radio stream. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46477571/3166697
But for production I use ExoPlayer from Google.