# Foreground service exception on Oreo

Tags: java, android

I called startForegroundService instead of startService in context:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      startForegroundService(intent);
  }else {
      startService(intent);
  }
```

And it called onStartCommand in LocationService:

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Channel of Location",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .build();
            startForeground(1, notification);
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            Notification notification = builder.build();

            startForeground(1, notification);
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

and i have an error like this:

> Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException:
>   Context.startForegroundService() did not then call
>   Service.startForeground()
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2101)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

Comment: call startForeground in onCreate

Comment: I've tried but still not working

Comment: you can find is an example  here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477571/a-notification-of-the-foreground-service-doesnt-show-on-android-8